# Accounting for differences in average teacher salaries, adjusted for inflation and the cost of living in each state

Tags: finance, education-economics

My aim is to determine whether teacher salaries in all 50 of the United States over between 2013 and 2023—adjusted for inflation and the cost of living—differ significantly. I would like to ask what the wisest approach might be to modify unadjusted teacher salary averages (there is one average for each state) to account for these effects.

Afterwards, I would like to graph these modified salaries for a few of these states and examine whether changes in revenue receipts within all schools in a particular state leads to a significant difference in average salaries.

I am open to your insight on how I might best tweak teachers’ salaries to account for these effects and things I ought to consider when graphing the relationship I’ve described. Please bear in mind that I am referring to information from the National Education Association, which sources from public schools.

Thank you!

Comment: [cross posting](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/121894) is generally [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/989943)